# Proof of a metric space axiom for $d(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)|dt$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

In a topology textbook, I found the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be the set of all continuous functions $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$.
>
> For $f,g \in X$, define $$d(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)|dt.$$
> Using appropriate theorems from calculus, prove that $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

I approached this by proving the axioms one by one.

I showed that $d(f,g) \geq 0$ using the fact that the integrand is always positive or $0$, hence the integral has to be positive or equal to $0$.

Next I showed that $d(f,g)=0 \iff f=g$. This follows from the fact that the integrand is non-negative; therefore, for the integral to be $0$, the integrand has to be identically $0$ on the interval on which the integral is defined. Now for the integrand to be $0$, we need $|f(t)-g(t)|=0$, which is equivalent to $f(t)=g(t)$.

For the third axiom, I used the identity that $|x-y|=|y-x|$, which implies that $$d(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)|dt=\int_{a}^{b}|g(t)-t(t)|dt =d(g,f).$$

The last axiom is where I am having trouble.
I need to prove that $$\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-h(t)|dt  \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)|dt + \int_{a}^{b}|g(t)-h(t)|dt,$$
which would imply that
$$d(f,h) \leq d(f,g) + d(g,h).$$

I've tried rearranging the integrals and changing their form to show it, but I can't seem to get there. How would I go about proving this?

Comment: $|f(t)-h(t)|\leq |f(t)-g(t)| + |g(t)-h(t)|$. Integrate both sides.

Comment: You have to be a little careful with how you show that $d(f,g)=0$ means $f=g$. In general, an integral being 0 doesn't mean the integrand is 0. You should make it clear why it being continuous and positive implies that.

Comment: @geetha290krm From that statement I can get to the result, but I'm not sure how you got this inequality. Can you show how to find this?

Comment: that’s just the triangle inequality for real numbers

Comment: @Eric No worries, I have explained why that implication is true further in my notes. But since this is unrelated to the problem I am having I only shortly mentioned it in this post.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I get it now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer:

It can be solved by integrating the triangle inequality for real numbers:

$$ \begin{align}
|f(t)−h(t)|&≤|f(t)−g(t)|+|g(t)−h(t)| \\
\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-h(t)|dt  &\leq \int_{a}^{b} (|f(t)-g(t)| + |g(t)-h(t)|)dt \\
\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-h(t)|dt  &\leq \int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)|dt + \int_{a}^{b}|g(t)-h(t)|dt \\
d(f,h) &\leq d(f,g) + d(g,h)
\end{align}$$